# Spring Integration - @ServiceActivator with Poller

Tags: spring-integration

I am working on annotation based Spring integration project.
I tried to write @ServiceActivator with a Poller but the problem is that the message polling happens for exactly 3 times and then stops. What could be the issue here?

Same polling works perfectly fine with @InboundChannelAdapter but just wondering why doesn't it work with ServiceActivator.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this error happens when you hold a polling thread. You may have some gateway in the middle (somewhere downstream on that `outputChannel`) that expects some reply, but you don't send one. It's hard to say what is going on without more config from your application.

What is the whole flow after that `outputChannel` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.This is absolutely correct. I had a gateway interrupting in between, removing it works fine.